# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null, fetching data directly from firebase rtdb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why my state is not updating with the data that im fetching directly from direbase
[image]

Where im getting data in console

[image]

What im doing wrong here,
Error is here
[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  You should copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
const db = firebase.database().ref('users/trainers/'+uid).on('value', function(snapshot){
   // here this refers to the firebase callback scope 
    this.setState({
        .........
        .........
    })
}))
```

into this:

```
const db = firebase.database().ref('users/trainers/'+uid).on('value', (snapshot) =>{
   // here this refers to the firebase callback scope 
    this.setState({
        .........
        .........
    })
}))
```

Use arrow functions:

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this from its enclosing scope.

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem is your `this` is not in the scope, `this` in here refers to firebase callback scope. You can console `this` and check.

```
const db = firebase.database().ref('users/trainers/'+uid).on('value', function(snapshot){
   // here this refers to the firebase callback scope 
    this.setState({
        .........
        .........
    })
}))
```

Fix you can do is

```
const that = this;
const db = firebase.database().ref('users/trainers/'+uid).on('value', function(snapshot){
    // now `that` holds your class LogPro1 scope, now you can setState using that.setState()
    that.setState({
        .........
        .........
    })
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your getData() method definition like below,

```
getData = () => {
   ... As the above code
}
```

**OR**

bind this to the getData method in the constructor.

```
constructor() {
   super(props);
   this.state = { email: '', firstName: '', lastName: '' }
   this.getData = this.getData.bind(this); // Binding this context to getData method
}
```

Comment: Ive worked on bind before, but this time its giving me "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined" + your first solution is not working too